# c# encoding string to unknown format

Tags: c#, encoding, character

I know a website that converts special characters but I don't know what is encoded format.
example : 
When I search `uğur` in website, it converts to `ug21ur` in URL.
Is it an encoding format or? How can I convert a `ğ` to `g21` in C#?

Example : http://www.behindthename.com/name/ug21ur

Comment: What website? I don't see any encoding for `ğ` that encodes as 21.

Comment: search 'uğur' in http://www.behindthename.com and look at URL.

Comment: The website only mentions that it encodes the characters, but no info on how they do it (http://www.behindthename.com/details.php). Maybe you can ask on their forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't help you, but I think it is specific to this website and not even really an encoding. Some examples:

```
uğur    ug21ur
DŽENAN  dzenan
NAĎA    nad18a
Naďa    nad18a
NADĚŽDA nade18z18da
```

I think these names are generated using some algorithm designed by the website's creator. Something like: if the character is special, suffix it with 18. If a name with the same representation is already present, increment the number. Just a guess and probably incorrect.

<sub>Internationalization is also seen abbreviated as i18n.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a 'formal' encoding.  Ordinarily, URL encoding would produce: `u%C4%9Fur`.

[This is a very good online resource](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) for converting to most encodings.  However, in this case, I don't see any encoding that would correspond to `g21` for your character.